# How can I download a logfile from Swisscom cloud foundry

Tags: download, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I use ELK and write some additional (extensive) log information to a file called extensive.log.

How can I download this file to my local hard drive for further analysis?

I tried the [cf-download](https://github.com/ibmjstart/cf-download) plugin. But I do get a "permission or corrupt" error.

`$ cf download app-name /home/SOME-PATH/logs/extensive.log`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need any plugins, you can use `scp` or `sftp`.

The documentation is [here](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/diego-ssh#cloud-foundry-via-cloud-controller-and-uaa), but this is a summary:

1. `cf login` and `cf target`
2. `cf curl /v2/info | jq .app_ssh_endpoint` this is your SSH host
3. `cf ssh-code` then copy the value, this is your password
4. `cf app app-name --guid` this is part of your user name
5. `sftp -P 2222 cf:<app-guid>/<app-instance-num>@<ssh-host>`, when prompted for a password, enter the passcode you copied in step #3.

Similarly, for `scp` you can run `scp -P 2222 -oUser=cf:<app-guid>/<app-instance-num> my-local-file.json <ssh-host>:my-remote-file.json`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! I tweaked it a bit so I can simply paste the password:
`cf ssh-code | pbcopy && sftp -P 2222 cf:<app-guid/0@<ssh-host>:/home/SOME-PATH/logs/extensive.log`